# Hyper-V Integration for Debian 8

Tags: debian, hyper-v

As per https://oitibs.com/install-hyper-v-lis-on-debian-8/ i need to edit `nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` however i noticed that even without this, nor installing `apt-get install hyperv-daemons`, out of the box the following modules get loaded:

```
root@svr1:/home/jason# lsmod | grep hv_*
hv_balloon             20874  0
hv_utils               17718  0
hv_storvsc             21296  3
scsi_mod              191405  4 sg,sd_mod,sr_mod,hv_storvsc
hv_netvsc              30494  0
hv_vmbus               65661  7 hv_balloon,hyperv_keyboard,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_utils,hyperv_fb,hv_storvsc
```

Are these full Hyper-V components ready from first install?

If so, what is being installed when we run `apt-get install hyperv-daemons`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know what a package does you should read the package summary.  The command `apt-cache show hyperv-daemons` will show you the summary, or look at the [package page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/hyperv-daemons). It seems pretty clear about what is included.  On the package page you can also click a link to show a list of the files.

> Suite of daemons for Linux guests running on Hyper-V, consisting of hv_fcopy_daemon, hv_kvp_daemon and hv_vss_daemon.

Installed files

```
/lib/systemd/system/hyperv-daemons.hv-fcopy-daemon.service
/lib/systemd/system/hyperv-daemons.hv-kvp-daemon.service
/lib/systemd/system/hyperv-daemons.hv-vss-daemon.service
/usr/sbin/hv_fcopy_daemon
/usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon
/usr/sbin/hv_vss_daemon
/usr/share/doc/hyperv-daemons/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/hyperv-daemons/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/hyperv-daemons/copyright
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply will accept your answer, so the daemons are different from the modules that are loaded? How come the modules don't need to be edited in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`?